# How to config password for redis in jhipster?

Tags: redis, jhipster

refer to this link, https://www.jhipster.tech/common-application-properties/
I cannot find the solution to config password for redis

```
jhipster:
  http:
    cache: # Used by the CachingHttpHeadersFilter
      timeToLiveInDays: 1461
  cache: # Cache configuration
    redis: # Redis configuration
      expiration: 3600 # By default objects stay 1 hour (in seconds) in the cache
      server: redis://localhost:6379
```

Comment: I suspect it's not a JHipster specific property. Have you tried standard Spring Boot properties?  Like `spring.redis.password`

Comment: As @GaëlMarziou said,  at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html the property is spring.redis.password | Login password of the redis server.

The class io.github.jhipster.config.JHipsterProperties.Cache.Redis only has the properties expiration and server (Jhipster version 6.5.1)

Answer (score 0):

```
.setAddress(jHipsterProperties.getCache().getRedis().getServer()).setDatabase(1)
.setPassword("your password");`
```

Comment: Hi Gaofen. Please explain your solution!

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
jhipster:
  cache: # Cache configuration
    redis: # Redis configuration
      expiration: 3600 # By default objects stay 1 hour (in seconds) in the cache
      server: redis://:654321@127.0.0.1:6379 # redis://:your-redis-server-password@your-redis-server-ip:your-redis-server-port

      cluster: false
```